# Why my androiv virtual device only opens the google page in my WebView?

Tags: android

If I write

```
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

The google page opens normally, but if I put another addres, like

```
webView.loadUrl("http://www.android.com");
```

The page does not open. Is this a bug with my AVD?
It does not appears anyone error message. I try for other pages, like Bing, and the web page opens normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for Android in the Google search in your emulator does it search and produce results? What exactly is the browser doing when you try to load up a webpage? Don't forget some pages use Https instead of Http although http://www.Android.com should have worked. If nothing else go into the AVD manager and create a new emulator and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Yes, I access the android site normally using the emulator browser. I will try to create another emulator and try again. But I have no hopes. Because I tried this before.